# Error in multithreading prog in java

Tags: java, multithreading

[image]

I am having this problem when i run the given code for multithreading, cannot understand why..
I am providing the code as well as output screenshot.

```
import java.lang.*;

class A extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            if (i == 1) {
                yield();
            }
            System.out.println("\tFrom Thread A i: " + i);
        }
        System.out.println("Exit from A");
    }
}

class B extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
            System.out.println("\tFrom Thread B j: " + j);
            if (j == 3)
                stop();
        }
        System.out.println("Exit from B");
    }
}

class C extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        for (int k = 1; k < 6; k++) {
            System.out.println("\tFrom Thread C k: " + k);
            if (k == 1)
                try {
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
        }
        System.out.println("Exit from C");
    }
}

class Thread {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A threadA = new A();
        B threadB = new B();
        C threadC = new C();
        System.out.println("Start Thread A");
        threadA.start();
        System.out.println("Start Thread B");
        threadB.start();
        System.out.println("Start Thread C");
        threadC.start();
        System.out.println("End of main thread");
    }

}
```

Comment: Would you please post the stack trace in *textual* form?

Comment: Your local class `Thread` is used as the base class of `A`, `B`, and `C` instead of `java.lang.Thread`.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you use your class Thread and there are no method called start().
Change the class name from Thread to MyThread and it should work.

Change it in that way:

```
class A extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++) {
            if (i == 1) {
                yield();
            }
            System.out.println("\tFrom Thread A i: " + i);
        }
        System.out.println("Exit from A");
    }
}

class B extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        for (int j = 1; j < 6; j++) {
            System.out.println("\tFrom Thread B j: " + j);
            if (j == 3)
                stop();
        }
        System.out.println("Exit from B");
    }
}

class C extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        for (int k = 1; k < 6; k++) {
            System.out.println("\tFrom Thread C k: " + k);
            if (k == 1)
                try {
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
        }
        System.out.println("Exit from C");
    }
}

public class MyThread {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        A threadA = new A();
        B threadB = new B();
        C threadC = new C();
        System.out.println("Start Thread A");
        threadA.start();
        System.out.println("Start Thread B");
        threadB.start();
        System.out.println("Start Thread C");
        threadC.start();
        System.out.println("End of main thread");
    }

}
```

Comment: I actually downvoted this. I'm not a fan of doing all of OP's homework.

Comment: There is no comment or something like that, which indicates that the question is homework.

Comment: meant in the broad sense of the term :)

Comment: And I solved only the naming problem the rest of the code is the example of the questioner

Answer (score 2):

You are redefining class `Thread`, thus [shadowing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) `java.lang.Thread`.

Either rename your class or use

```
class A extends java.lang.Thread
```

in place of `class A extends Thread` (and likewise for `B` and `C`).

Answer (score 2):

Or simply precise your inheritance by changing:

```
class B extends Thread
```

to:

```
class B extends java.lang.Thread
```

for your classes `A`, `B` and `C`.

Answer (score 1):

Rename your class Thread. Here you actually want to java.lang.Thread but it is being hidden by your own (local) Thread class.